# How can I mockup the ip of my android device?

Tags: android, proxy, ip

I'm developing a mobile search engine, some people in another country has said that the app doesn't work very well in their country, I suspect that is a server side thing. I want test it with my own device, but theres no way that I can find to mockup my device's ip address to their country ip address. I tried with several proxy apps without result. How can I test in this situation?.

Comment: Why didn't the proxy apps work?

Comment: I highly doubt a different IP address would interfere. It'd be more of a question of what's between those users and your server. e.g. great firewall of china. mocking a chinese ip in your simulator isn't going to simulate that firewall

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Also, go to Settings > Developer Option > and enable "Allow mock locations"

It's under "Debugging" category

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself very well. I'm trying to mockup the ip, not the location.